# Data corruption due to opening a new file in C

Tags: c, file, pointers, reference, file-handling

I have the following code wherein, I return a memory address to a pointer whose location in which I store a string.
The code looks something like this:

```
char* segs[1];
segs[0] = (char *) myfunction("name", 100);
//myfunction(Name,size of the memory to be allocated)

FILE *write_log;
write_log = fopen(redo_path,"a+");
```

The function myfunction returns a memory location which is fixed as the base address of segs[0].
The memory allocation in my goes along the lines of:

```
FILE *fp_seg;
fp_seg = fopen(compare,"r");
//maps from disk to mem
void *p;
p = (void *)malloc(size_to_create); //Mapping
int c;
c = fread(p,size_to_create,1,fp_seg);
```

We open a file on disk and generate a corresponding mapping of the address of the first location in the file. (p is more of a reference to the first location in the file).

**ISSUE:**

Opening an existing file with the write_log file pointer corrupts the contents of the string stored at the memory location segs[0].Upon debugging, I figured out that the memory regions spanned by the file and the segs[0] overlap, i.e.

`segs[0]` had a memory location of `0x1cc5de0` and stored `"Hello, world"`.

`write_log` had a memory location of `0x1cc5d50`

My guess is that opening a file at that location corrupts the contents of `seg[0]`.

How do I overcome this issue? Is there a way to allocate memory such that the regions do not overlap?

**EDIT:**
My function is something like this:

```
myfunction(char * compare, int size_to_create)
{
//size_to_create is the size of the memory we want to allocate to seg[0]
//Create a file with the name compare in the disk
FILE *fp_seg;
fp_seg = fopen(compare,"r");

//Read the file (File has no content as of now)

void *p;
p = (void *)malloc(size_to_create); //p has an address in main memory
int c;
c = fread(p,size_to_create,1,fp_seg);

void *t;
t=p;
//Future reads will have the same mapping 

free(p); 
}
```

Comment: I tried, but I really can't follow this description. Please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Okay. I shall update the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the freeing of the pointer p, which deallocates the memory.

Thus there is no restriction on the system to not allocate the region originally pointed by p to another part of the code requesting memory.